# Laravel between dates

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to check the validity of promo code by comparing date in eloquent but dont know why its not working

```
$promoCode = self::where('code', $code)
        ->where('start_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
        ->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
        ->first();
```

If i comment out 2nd and 3rd line then it works fine. MySQL column type is **date**. I also tried **whereDate** method and thats not working too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you inverted the signs. You are looking for something that is older than `start_date` and younger than `end_date`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the start_date be before now. If so now should be between. Try:

```
$promoCode = self::where('code', $code)
    ->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
    ->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
    ->first();
```